# How to create two producer kafka templates in kafka using spring which accepts different data types One is JsonNode and the other Avro?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm trying to develop two producer configuration classes with different Serialization types(JSONNode, Avro) but, at runtime I'm able to instantiate only one , the other one is not working.

First class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaProducerConfig extends SomeClassConfig{
@Autowired
    private SomeClassProps someClassProps ;

@Bean
    public ProducerFactory<JsonNode, JsonNode> eventProducerFactory() throws UnknownHostException{
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<JsonNode, JsonNode>(producerConfigs(someClassProps ));
}

@Bean
public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs(SomeClassProps someClassProps ) throws UnknownHostException{
    Properties props = this.initProps(someClassProps );
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, ***.getBootstrapServers());      
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonSerializer");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonSerializer");
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (final String name: props.stringPropertyNames()) {
        map.put(name, props.getProperty(name));         
    }
    
    return map;
}

@Bean(name="eventProducerKafkaTemplate")
public KafkaTemplate<JsonNode,JsonNode> eventProducerKafkaTemplate() throws UnknownHostException{       
    return new KafkaTemplate<JsonNode,JsonNode>(eventProducerFactory());
}
```

}

Second class:

```
@Configuration("avroKafkaProducerConfig")
@EnableKafka
public class AvroKafkaProducerConfig extends SomeClassConfig{

    //private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaProducerConfig.class);
        @Autowired
private SomeClassProps someClassProps ;
    
    @Bean(name = KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration.DEFAULT_STREAMS_CONFIG_BEAN_NAME)
    public StreamsConfig kafkaStreamsConfig(SomeClassProps someClassProps ) throws UnknownHostException {
        Map<String, Object> props = producerConfigs(someClassProps );
        return new StreamsConfig(props);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<SpecificRecord, SpecificRecord> eventProducerFactory() throws UnknownHostException{
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<SpecificRecord, SpecificRecord>(producerConfigs(someClassProps ));
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs(SomeClassProps someClassProps ) throws UnknownHostException{
        Properties props = this.initProps(someClassProps );
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, ***.getBootstrapServers());      
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
        Map<String, Object> map = (Map) props;
        System.out.println("Avro"+map.values());
        
        return map;
    }
    
    @Bean(name="eventAvroProducerKafkaTemplate")
    public KafkaTemplate<SpecificRecord,SpecificRecord> eventProducerKafkaTemplate() throws UnknownHostException{       
        return new KafkaTemplate<SpecificRecord,SpecificRecord>(eventProducerFactory());
    }
```

}

when I'm trying to use these kafka templates in my controller class it is only intializing the Json Serializer not the avro one.

THis is how I'm using these kafka templates in other class

```
@Autowired
    @Qualifier("eventProducerKafkaTemplate")
    private KafkaTemplate<JsonNode, JsonNode> eventProducerKafkaTemplate;

    @Autowired
     @Qualifier("eventAvroProducerKafkaTemplate")
    private KafkaTemplate<SpecificRecord,SpecificRecord> eventAvroProducerKafkaTemplate;


public ReturnTYpe methodName() {

eventProducerKafkaTemplate.send(****, ****, ****);
eventAvroProducerKafkaTemplate.send(****, ****, ****);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must give the 2 `producerConfigs` and 2 `eventProducerFactory` beans different method (bean) names. Otherwise one overrides the other.